# How to use production webserver configuration locally

Tags: testing, nginx, webserver

I'm using Nginx virtual hosts to serve a domain and I want to test my configuration locally before deploying.

The only way I've found to do that is to run nginx on local port 80 and temporarily add the following line to my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
```

which causes `example.com` to resolve to my local nginx instance.

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: There may be better solutions depending on your specific needs, but what you're doing is definitely a solid test, and what I do.  Nginx configs aren't something I'm changing often, so I don't find this to be too difficult.  If you're testing these changes frequently, you could always script it.

Comment: @Brad, yeah, I posted this question whilst contemplating writing a shell script. I'm mostly concerned that I'll forget about it some day and be on the phone with a client arguing about what their site looks like.

Comment: Do you find yourself testing your Nginx config so frequently?  If you're just doing this to test the site itself, I recommend using a different hostname.  in my workflow, I use the `vagrant-hostmanager` plugin with my Vagrant box, and a development hostname like `www.dev.example.com`.

Comment: @Brad, no I don't do it that frequently which is why I'm afraid I'll forget, haha. Lately I've been tracking down what I suspect is a bug in a framework's url/port rewriting which I can't reproduce in dev.

Answer (score 0):

### Local Host

When I just need to quickly check a server running on my local host, the following shell script has proven convenient:

```sh
spoof() {
        hosts_file='/etc/hosts'
        temp=$(mktemp)

        cp "$hosts_file" "$temp"
        trap 'sudo sh -c "mv \"$temp\" \"$hosts_file\""; trap "" EXIT; return 0' 0 1 2 3 9 15

        hosts_lines="6i# SPOOFS:\n"
        for i in "$@"; do
                hosts_lines+="127.0.0.1\t$i\n"
                shift
        done
        sudo sh -c "sed -i \"$hosts_lines\" \"$hosts_file\""

        echo "Press CTRL-C to exit..."
        sleep infinity
}
```

It takes any number of domains, spoofs them, and replaces the original `/etc/hosts` upon exit. Example usage:

```
$ spoof example.com example.net example.org
```

### Vagrant

For long-term use, I use Vagrant along with the [vagrant-hostsupdater](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater) plugin.

After installing, simply adding `config.hostsupdater.aliases = ['dev.example.com']` to any Vagrantfile allows access to "example.com" on the VM via "dev.example.com" on the host.